# Add Java code Template XML file in the project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have 2 `XML` files as `Java code formatting for Intellij` and `Java code Templates` to set in the IntelliJ. I set the first file in the `Editor -> Code Style -> Java`. I think I need to set the 2nd file in the `Editor -> File and code templates` as provided by the screenshot.

[image]

I provided the sample for the Java code Templates file below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
   <template autoinsert="true" context="gettercomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for getter method" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.codetemplates.gettercomment" name="gettercomment">/**
 * @return the ${bare_field_name}
 */</template>
   <template autoinsert="true" context="overridecomment_context" deleted="false" description="Comment for overriding methods" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.codetemplates.overridecomment" name="overridecomment">/* (non-Javadoc)
 * ${see_to_overridden}
 */</template>

  .....................
  .....................

</templates>
```

However, I don't see the specific option to add an XML file. How to do it?

PS:

I think the question is better asked as `"I have a license file as XML 
   format. How do I use import and it in the IntelliJ?"`?

Comment: There is no separate import/export for File and Code templates. File and Code templates are stored under the "[IDE config](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)/fileTemplates" directory. So you could try to place file there, provided that this is correct file template you will see it in IDE File and Code templates under **Files** tab.

Comment: Also if you have an access to IDE instance where you want to import it from you can use File | [Import/Export action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings) to import and export settings, including File and Code template via the .jar file.

Comment: @Andrey I wasn't able to make it as a comment, so, I need to do manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's mentioned in the comment, there are no separate import/export options of the XML template files on the `File and Code templates` tab (or anywhere else). I tried to follow the info provided in the comment and it didn't work out. So, I had to transport all the info there manually as provided,

[image]

[image]